# NumberFormatException when accessing list of objects in JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring Boot by creating a simple student application. I am getting a NumberFormatException while accessing the collection of "Student" objects returned by the controller to the view.

The controller is returning a List of "Student" objects and I am trying to display an added record through JSP view.

**Controller Class**

```
    package com.example.spring02;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class SampleController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public SampleController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/students")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("students", studentService.getAllStudents());
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addStudent")
    public String addStudent(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        return "addStudent";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addStudent")
    public String addStudent(Student student) {
        studentService.addStudent(student);
        return "home";
    }

}
```

**Student**

```
package com.example.spring02;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Student() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!!!!</h1>
<div>
    <c:forEach items="${students}" var="s">
        <p><c:out value="${s.id}" /></p>
        <p><c:out value="${s.name}" /></p>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Exception Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.0.M26.jar:3.0.FR]
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.0.M26.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) ~[tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184) ~[tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:702) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(home_jsp.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(home_jsp.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]

2017-08-26 20:15:53.790 ERROR 17972 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"] with root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.0.M26.jar:3.0.FR]
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.0.M26.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) ~[tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184) ~[tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:702) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(home_jsp.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(home_jsp.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.0.M26.jar:9.0.0.M26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: Probably duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375093/spring-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Thanks for the response. I'm returning objects differently in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```
private int id;
private String name;

public Student() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

to:

```
private String id;
private String name;

public Student() {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Have you restarted Tomcat?

Comment: I'm using embedded tomcat that comes with Spring Boot.